# how to create a subdomian on a windows server 2003 network

Tags: windows, domain, forwarding

I'm trying to forward 'test.mydomain.com' to '192.168.10.34'. That is a centos web server. However I can't seem to figure out or find how to do this in Windows Server 2003. We do own mydomain.com and its operational and using IIS. Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Is the goal to make `test.mydomain.com` reachable from the Internet?

Comment: Yes that is my goal.

Comment: What sits between your network and the Internet?  Is it a router?  Full firewall?

Comment: centos machine -> windows server 03 (DNS) -> Barracuda firewall -> cisco router -> isp

Comment: Do you already host a site on your public IP?

Comment: Is the DNS running on the same box as the IIS?

Answer (score 1):

If your DNS is running on the Windows Server 2003 box then you go to DNS Manager, Forward Lookup Zones - Select your domain and create a new Host (A) record with your Name set to Test and your IP address to the address you want it to forward to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add record to your external DNS for `mydomain.com` that points `test.mydomain.com` to the public address of your router.  You then need to set up a firewall rule to forward the requests for `test.mydomain.com` to your centos box.  That should be all that is necessary, with the possible addition of making sure the Cisco router does actually route the incoming requests to the firewall.